# how to select pieces of 2 lists using np.sign?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 separate lists which I would like to select some pieces of both. In the first variable set, I need to select based on its sign then when I could have `zero crossing`, I should select from both lists based on the indices coming from `zero_crossing`.
I could define the function to have zero_crossing indices but I do not know how to select from both lists using the indices.

```
def func_1(arr1):
    for i, a in enumerate(arr1):
        zero_crossings = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(arr1)))[0]
    return zero_crossings
def func_2(arr1,arr2):
    res_list1 = []
    res_list2 = []
    for i in (zero_crossings):
        res_list1.append(arr1[i:i+1])
        res_list2.append(arr2[i:i+1])
zero_crossing = [3,12,18]
list1 = [-12,-14,-16,-10,1,3,6,2,,1,5,5,3,-1,-12,-2,-3,-5,-3,3,2,5,2]
list2 = [0.00040409 0.00041026 0.0004162  ... 0.00116538 0.001096   0.00102431]
```

```
The expected results:
new_list_1 = [list1[0:3]+list1[3:12]+list1[12:18]]
new_list_1 = [list2[0:3]+list2[3:12]+list2[12:18]]
```

```
for i in range(len(zero_crossing)):
    list_{%d} = []
    list_i = list1[zero_crossing[i]:zero_crossing[i+1]]
```

I want to use `list1` to see where we have a change in `sign` then through the list of indices of `sign changing`, try to select the values of both lists.
All efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: I dont fully understand what you try to do. Could you give a minimal working example with the expected output?

Comment: In function func_1, why is zero_crossing assigned the same value for every loop?  How does function func_2 know about zero_crossings?

Comment: @some_name.py I did it

Comment: @DarrylG I edited the question to make it a bit clear

Comment: So why don't you just do new_list_1=list_1[0:18]... isn't that the same?

Comment: @some_name.py seems the same, but I needed to do it since I need to consider each part of the array separately. I mean the arrays substitute with sub-lists to study each sub-list separately

Comment: Sry then I don't fully understand. If you manged to get the zero_crossings your last edit is more or less answering your question. Maybe also look into the concept of slices.